# Name of distribution with density normal times polynomial (polynormal?)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology, normal-distribution

Is there a name for a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ whose density is is given by $f(x)g(x)$, where
$$f(x) = (2\pi \sigma)^{-1/2} \exp(-(x-\mu)^2/\sigma)$$
is the density of a normal distribution and $g(x)$ is polynomial in $x$? My specific use-case is where
$$g(x) =  (P + Qx^2).$$
My instinct is to call this "polynormal" but that might imply the law of $h(X)$, where $h$ is a polynomial and $X$ is normally distributed.